# Cannot install NuGet packages to PCL - "package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework"

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, nuget

I am trying to follow a tutorial on consuming web services in Xamarin Forms. I created a fresh project and have tried to install [Refit](https://github.com/paulcbetts/refit), that didn't work so I tried to install [RestSharp](https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp). I can install both of these libraries to my Droid / iOS projects, but not to the PCL. I get the following error in Visual Studio:

`Could not install package 'Refit 4.0.1'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets '.NETPortable,Version=v4.5,Profile=Profile111', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author`

`Could not install package 'RestSharp 106.2.1'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets '.NETPortable,Version=v4.5,Profile=Profile111', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author`

I've found [this post on the xamarin forums](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/80045/error-using-nuget), but it didn't fix my issue. My project is fresh, everything is up to date... Does anyone know how I can fix this issue?

*vents* XF is supposed to make developing cross platform apps faster & easier, but i think I'd have done this poc in native ios/droid twice in the time it's taken me to install a library to a blank project! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because RestSharp it's not compatible with PCL-library. So you will have to handle whatever you're trying to do in platform specific.

Comment: Thanks i had no idea!